# jQuery wrap not working with append?

Tags: javascript, jquery

1. I have a `p` element `<p id="test">Test</p>` and wrap it inside a `span` by using `wrap` and save the new element under `$test`.
2. I append `$test` to `p#output`.

**Result**: `p` element is getting appended, but it is not wrapped inside a span anymore.

```js
$test = $("p#test").wrap("<span style='color:red'></span>");
$("p#output").append($test);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="test">Test</p>
<p id="output">OUTPUT:</p>
```

Comment: [`.wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/): "The .wrap() function can take any string or object that could be passed to the $() factory function to specify a DOM structure. This structure may be nested several levels deep, but should contain only one inmost element. A copy of this structure will be wrapped around each of the elements in the set of matched elements. **This method returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.**"

Comment: You can't wrap a `<p>` in a `<span>`. That's invalid HTML. You can see it for yourself when you inspect the resultant code. The browser tries to correct that for you by moving the elements around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery documentation says `.wrap()` returns the original set of elements for chaining purposes.

use something like this instead `$("p#output").append($('p#test').parent());`

Comment: because it still wraps the DOM element on the page, but if you need to then move the element (and it's new parent) you need to use something like what I put above

Comment: alternatively you could do the `append` THEN `wrap` that should also work